# How to unwrap a 1:1 Ratio UV Map?

Tags: uv

I am trying to unwrap my model (simple cube) but I don't want the 
traditional "Smart UV Project" unwrap.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/4cpmxsD.png]

I'd rather much want it to unwrap like so. (Done manually)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqmrK.png]

(Reason why is because I use a single texture for my model, for simplicity
and I want it to be a 1:1 ratio in the scale of things, I also Mark all the seams for each "flat surface", so a wall with a hole in it, would be one surface, if there's a slope, that slope becomes it's own "surface")

Thanks in advance

Comment: Had you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

mark those edges as "seams":

[image]

then  a simple UV unwrap gives:

[image]

Comment: You must've misunderstood, problably didn't ask properly. I want the Unwrap to scale accordingly to what the size of the model itself is. So if a wall on my model is 8 "units" long, I want the Unwrap to be 8 units long, OUTSIDE the initial area https://i.imgur.com/bXmBorV.png

Comment: This is after I did everything manually. https://i.imgur.com/Zw1eyY4.png  The square bottom left is the 0 to 1 UV "area", I want the UV "squares" to scale from 0 to 1 according to how large they **really** are, if possible even without doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with "[Magic UV](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/uv/magic_uv.html)" add-on.

The functionality can be found under "[Manual Word Scale UV](https://github.com/nutti/Magic-UV/wiki/Tutorial#mode-manual)"

[image]

**You have to set scale equal to size of the texture.**

[image]